# Slider doesn't load images in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a slider in bootstrap modal which doesn't load images to show and i need to resize the window to load them.

`$(window).resize()` does resize the modal and solves my problem but in response view it doesn't. I tried almost all kind of resizing.

Here is where i call `resize()` method:

```
$(".cbp-pagination-item").on('click',function() {
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Comment: Please add the code you have for the slider, you don't need to add the entire file but just what is involved with the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was happened when i was trying to place my slider code

```
$('#js-grid-slider-thumbnail').cubeportfolio({some-properties: somthings});
```

between below code.

```
$(document).ready()
```

And when i leaved slider code outside of that, one problem solved as there were not any img tag with zero size any more. But yet image was not loaded until i used below function.

```
setTimeOut(function(){})
```

So my final code became something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
            $('#js-grid-slider-thumbnail').cubeportfolio({
                layoutMode: 'slider',
                drag: true,
                auto: false,
                //And some another properties
            });
    }, 600);
```

And i didn't need to use below code any more to load images.

```
$(window).resize();
```